# Sequences with indexes of the same order of magnitude

Tags: real-analysis

I need a help with this. Consider a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_{a_n} \rightarrow 0$. If the sequence $b_n$ is of the same order of magnitude as $a_n$ (that is, $b_n = O(a_n)$ and $a_n = O(b_n)$) then $x_{b_n} \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily: let

$$x_n=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;,\end{cases}$$

let $a_n=2n$, and let $b_n=2n+1$.